# Pupdate only 1 or 2 filter out of n (you can say 5) in list view

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to programatically update only 1 or 2 filter conditions out of N (you can say 5) in custom list view?

Answer (score 0):

First retrieve the SPView object:

```
SPView myView=myList.Views[guid];
```

Access and edit the view's query using its **Query** property. It is actually a string in CAML format. If you do not know about CAML query and/or how to set CAML filters, read this:
[MSDN CAML Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx)

```
myView.Query="<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>my item</Value></BeginsWith></Where>";
myView.Update();
```

Alternatively, you can choose to update view query by altering the current query. That would be a bit more complicated because you have to either use XmlDocument or deal with some string processing.

Comment: Ya its working. I trim query and add my mydata in that field and surprisingly its working perfect.. :)

Thanks a lot Paiman

Comment: Don't mention it Sweety. You can mark this as answer by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer below the 0.